# Apache Tiles doesn't work without any errors. -Maven Spring MVC

Tags: java, apache, maven, spring-mvc, tiles

I tried to add tiles to my project and I do this in many ways to do this properly. Finally i don't have any errors but still tiles didn't work on any web page.

Below my dependecies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
    <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.3</version>
</dependency>

 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.25</version>
</dependency>
```

And mine servlet:

```
<bean id="tilesViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView" />
    <property name="order" value="-2" />
</bean>

<bean id="tilesConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/tiles/definitions/tile-definition.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I don't know what more informations could help to unravel that mystery.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your maven dependencies, it looks like you have just added tiles-extras dependency. You need to add below dependencies for tiles to work,

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-template</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
```